# Add a static block to one page checkout in Magento via local.xml

Tags: magento, checkout

I would like to add a CMS static block (basket_shipping_message) just above the available shipping methods in my Magento checkout. I can edit the phtml file but would rather do it via my local.xml file.

The following code doesen't seem to be working, any ideas?

```
<checkout_onepage_index>    

    <reference name="content">

        <reference name="shipping_method">

                <block type="cms/block" name="basket_shipping_message" before="available">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>basket_shipping_message</block_id></action>
                </block>

        </reference>

    </reference>

</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you call in your phtml template getChildHtml('basket_shipping_message');? That should do it. Without that magento does not render the block